# session.run(LOAD CSV) issues

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, load-csv

When using **LOAD CSV** function with ***session.run()*** to execute cypher statements into Neo4J it doesn't return anything. Have tried removing **LOAD CSV** and it works perfectly fine in creating nodes.

This is the code:

```
import { neo4jgraphql } from "neo4j-graphql-js";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
const {createWriteStream} = require("fs");
const {GraphQLUpload} = require("apollo-server");
import {session} from "./index.js"

/*
 * Check for GRAPHQL_SCHEMA environment variable to specify schema file
 * fallback to schema.graphql if GRAPHQL_SCHEMA environment variable is not set
 */
const files = [];
export const typeDefs = fs
  .readFileSync(
    process.env.GRAPHQL_SCHEMA || path.join(__dirname, "schema.graphql")
  )
  .toString("utf-8");

export const resolvers = {
//  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  Query: {
    files: () => files
  },
  Mutation: {
    uploadFile: async (_, {file}) => {
      const {createReadStream, filename } = await file;

      await new Promise(res =>
        createReadStream()
          .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "./uploads", filename)))
          .on("close", res)
        );
        session.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Connections.csv' AS csvLine CREATE(n)"); // This does not work with the LOAD CSV (Works with only CREATE(n))
        return true;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That LOAD CSV command will just invoke `CREATE (n)` once per line which will create a node with no label or properties. Try changing it to something like `CREATE (n:CsvNode) SET n.prop_1 = csvLine.header1` (where `header1` is one of the headers from your CSV) and see if nodes labelled :CsvNode get created.